# Civ 5 Multiplayer version mismatch Mac-pc

Tags: pc, civilization-5, macos, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I recently re-installed Civ 5 to play with my friends. We use to play over local network across both Mac and PC.

However this time when we tried I got a version mismatch. In the menu we all have the same version 1.0.3.279. I have a build number in between parentheses, but they don't (one other Mac user has one, he is able to connect to the PC players, I cannot).

None of us have any updates available. We have verified game files using steam but it hasn't helped. We all have all mods enabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you all have the same mods enabled with the most updated versions? It may not be a mac vs windows thing, it may be that mods have outdated or no longer viable versions if you have older mods since you last played.

Comment: I've got the same problem with a friend (on Mac) trying to join my room a few months ago, and even with no mods / dlc (so with a fresh installed game), he wasn't able to join our room

Answer (score 2):

There is an unfortunate reason for this, which can be found if you dig deeply enough, and it is that the Mac side of Civilization 5 recently had to undergo a substantial update (giving it a different version), and the corresponding update for the Windows side simply has not come out yet. This means cross-platform play is out of the question.

Sources for this are [here](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Civilization_V) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/1/1661194916748974393/).

Comment: from your source, there's actually a temp fix of joining a legacy beta if you are still on mojave